# Papa Rudin $4.22$ Theorem

Tags: analysis, hilbert-spaces, order-theory, orthonormal, maximum-principle

There is the theorem:

Every orthonormal set $B$ in a Hilbert space $H$ is contained in a maximal orthonormal set in $H$.

There is the proof:

Let $\mathscr P$ be the class of all orthonormal sets in $H$ which contain the given set $B$. Partially order $\mathscr P$ by set inclusion.($\subset$)

Since $B$ $\in$ $\mathscr P$, $\mathscr P$ $\neq$ $\emptyset$.

Hence $\mathscr P$ contains a maximal totally ordered class $\Omega$.

Let $S$ be the union of all members of $\Omega$.

It is clear that $B$ $\subset$ $S$.

I don't understand how it's clear that $B$ $\subset$ $S$ ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any member of $\Omega$ is a member of $\mathscr P$, hence contains $B$. Therefore the union of all members of $\Omega$ contains $B$.